# Template errors after migration Angular 6 -> 9

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I just did the migration from Angular 6 to Angular 9, one of the most important dependency could not be used on Angular 6.

I follow the steps from `ng update`:

- `ng update`
- `ng update rxjs`
- `ng update @angular/cli`
- `ng update @angular/core`

The problem is that I have now a lot of template errors, all relate to the same problems.

- `No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'`
- `No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'`

I found nothing on the web relate to theses error on v9 (only on v2).

Here is some parts related to the error:

- For the error about `ngModel`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control style-input-size" name="UserUpdatedUsername" [(ngModel)]="UserUpdated.username" #myKronozUserUpdatedUsername="ngModel" mdbActive required>
```

- For the error about `ngForm`

```
<form #editUserForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="editUserForm.valid && saveUpdateUser()" novalidate class="style-form-edit-user">
```

FormsModule is well imported in the `app.module.ts` (this is the only module inside the app).
app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "angular-csv-files": "^1.0.0",
    "chart.js": "2.5.x",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.x",
    "core-js": "2.4.x",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.x",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.x",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.x",
    "jarallax": "^1.10.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "ng-html-util": "1.0.x",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.3.0",
    "ng-uikit-pro-standard": "/!\ sensible value /!\",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "screenfull": "3.3.x",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "0.3.x",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5",
    "webpack": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.5"
  }
```

Did I miss something for the migration ?
Thanks.

Comment: You should update major versions individually and not several at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting errors because template only variables have been removed in Angular 9. This was done because they were typed as `any` and allowed for mutations. In general, this was an anti-pattern. Going forward, your elements will be strongly typed.

In Angular versions <= 8, the code below was valid. `#TranslateBtn` you could reference a `translate` property because it was typed as `any`.

```
<button
  #translateBtn
  (click)="translateBtn.translate = !translateBtn.translate"
>
  Translate
</button>
```

In Angular 9, `#translateBtn` will be of type `HTMLButtonElement`, which does not have the `translate` property. Instead, you would replace that functionality with an event calling a function on your component.

HTML:

```
<button (click)="ontTranslate()">
  Translate
</button>
```

TS:

```
export class PeopleListComponent {
  translateToWookiee = false;

  onTranslate(): void {
    this.translateToWookiee = !this.translateToWookiee;
  }
}
```

My answer came from this blog [article](https://brianflove.com/2019/12/12/angular-9-update-guide/) from Brian Love, Google Developer Expert in Angular and Web Technologies.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I will try to update angular major versions individually. 
Is this documentation wrong ? It is using the same pattern for ngModel as in the code https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control

Comment: @MartinPaucot I just tried to reproduce your issue. When I upgraded, VS Code initially reported the same errors you saw above. I tried to run the code anyway, and it still worked. Back in VS Code, I executed the `Developer: reload window` command and the errors VS Code was reporting went away so I think it must have been confused by the update. You can run this command by going to View => Command Palette and typing in `reload window` and the option should come up. This, of course, assumes you're using VS Code. This means the `ngForm` directive changes the type from `FormElement` to `ngForm`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to follow the official guide: https://update.angular.io/.

Suggest to first update to version 8. Then to version 9.

Following this pattern, should auto-handle all incompatibilities using Angular schematics tools.